# China Invitation Letter of Duly Authorized Unit

Tags: visas, china, invitation-letters

Does anyone know how much trouble it is for a Chinese company to prepare a "Invitation Letter of Duly Authorized Unit" (required for certain business visas).

Presumably they may have to send an employee to a government office and deal with queues? Would they have to go to the provincial capital or could it be dealt with in a smaller city?

It's useful to know how much obligation one has taken on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they need to send someone to one of a number of possible government offices. They'll have to show a reason for inviting a foreigner, do paperwork, and pay fees.

Going to the provincial capital is not necessary, but it is entirely possible that a small town wouldn't have the right office.

If you'll permit me a gross over-generalization, this won't be *trouble* to them, per se. Nobody likes it, but having to go to  government offices and wait in lines is a fact of life in China. They're pretty accommodated to it. From my experience - though I haven't filed one of these forms - it's generally several hours to half a working day at a minimum, depending on what you're doing and how busy it is (it's *never* empty). In some cases it's possible to make an appointment ahead of time, but this only mildly ameliorates the waiting.