# Chinese F visa for doing research for short term (2 months)

Tags: china

I am trying to go to China to do research for a short period (~2 months). It seems the visa type I should apply is "F". I got an invitation letter from the supervisor in China saying that he is inviting me and all the expenses will be paid.

However when I go to apply for the visa they said that I need to provide an "invitation letter of duly authorized unit". But when I contacted my supervisor it seems to get such a letter we (myself and the university in China) should have a license agreement, etc.

Do you think the visa type (F) I am applying is the right one? If it is so, how to get "invitation letter of duly authorized unit"?

Answer (score 2):

The University will have to arrange the letter. See the similar [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47094/china-invitation-letter-of-duly-authorized-unit).

You could try your luck with just an invitation letter on the institution letterhead and the name and copies of the ID documents of the professor. She should be able to email those documents.  The letter should have the official chop.

If they are unwilling to do that, I might question the legitimacy of the offer.